# Windows 10 unexpected error on System Restore

Tags: windows, windows-10

in Windows 10 when i'm trying to use `System Restore` i get this error:

[image]

how to resolve this problem. i think some service dont run in my system

Comment: Did you have tune up utilities installed by any chance?

Comment: @user1203297 i'm created restore point and now i want to recovery by that, but system restore doesnt work

Comment: Hi Mahdi, thanks - but my question was - did you ever have "tuneup utilities"  installed on this machine?

Comment: @user1203297 i have `TweakBit.PCSuite` software , but i'm uninstall that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your tweaking software's turned off system restore.

To re-enable:

1. Run **gpedit.msc**
2. Open following branch and go to > **Computer Configuration\Administrative Template\System\System Restore**
3. In the right pane, please configure the “**Turn off system restore**” policy. Please set it to **Not Configured**.

EDIT:
Try editing the following services via services.msc:

1. Microsoft Shadow Copy Provider - "Automatic" and started
2. Volume Shadow Copy - "Automatic" and started

Comment: after set to `Not Configure` must be restart system?

Comment: i get same error after restart system

Comment: after enable `Microsoft Shadow Copy Provider` and restart system i get same problem :(

Comment: why System Restore status is `off` ?

Comment: You mean the service? It's off? Well that's probably your issue. Turn it to automatic as with Microsoft Shadow Copy Provider and Volume Shadow Copy

Comment: `Microsoft Shadow Copy Provider` not in my windows services

Comment: i'm enable that. thanks. :) `System Restore` is disable by administrator. how to enable that?

Comment: In the start menu, type 'services.msc' then right click on it and click 'open as administrator' then try to enable it again.